# Noise Effect on Autoregressive Polynomial Roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, time-series, orthogonal-polynomials, noise

So suppose I have the following signal:

$$ x(t) = s(t) + n(t) $$

where $n(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{n}^{2})$ and $s(t)$ is an autoregressive process of order $P$. My question -- If I model $x(t)$ with an autoregressive process of order $P$, how are the roots of the estimated AR process related to the original?

---

I can think of some ideas:

From the paper **Bounding the Roots of Polynomials** by Holly P. Hirst and Wade T. Macey, the authors claim that the radius of the roots can be bounded by:

$$ | z| \leq \sum_{p=0}^{P-1} |a_{p}| $$

So then if $\hat{a}_{p}$ are the estimated AR coefficients, and we could say that $\hat{a}_{p} \sim \mathcal{N}(a_{p}, \sigma^{2}_{n})$, then we could estimate the pdf of $|z|$ and get some information that way.

However -- is that claim true? Can we simply say $\hat{a}_{p} \sim \mathcal{N}(a_{p}, \sigma^{2}_{n})$?

---

In the paper **The Effects of Noise on the Autoregressive Spectral
Estimator** by Steven Kay, the author shows that noise flattens the autoregressive spectrum, suggesting that the angle of the roots stays the same, but the magnitude moves towards the origin.

However, it isn't clear how the estimated coefficients $\hat{a}_{p}$ relate to the true coefficients $a_{p}$ due to noise.

---

TLDR Questions:

1. If I model a noisy signal with an autoregressive process of order $P$, how are the roots of the estimated AR process related to the AR process of the true underlying signal? Can we simply say $\hat{a}_{p} \sim \mathcal{N}(a_{p}, \sigma^{2}_{n})$?
2. Everything I see about bounding the roots of polynomials seems to care only about the radius, ie the magnitude of the roots. But what about the angle? Can we bound that at all via the coefficients?

Comment: $s(t)$ is an autoregressive process of order $P$. Its coefficients are $\{a_{p}\}_{p=0}^{P-1}$. The $\hat{a}_{p}$ might be found from the Yule Walker equations. https://allsignalprocessing.com/lessons/autoregressive-models-the-yule-walker-equations/

Comment: Do you mean $s(t) = h \ast w(t)$ where $w$ is a second gaussian white noise and $h$ is a stable all-pole filter and $t$ is a discrete variable ? Are you estimating the $a_p$ from the whole signal or just finitely many $t$ ? In the former case you know how the noise $n$ affects the covariance matrix, no random variable involved.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is the definition of a true AR process. I suppose I am estimating it over the whole signal -- at least, all the signal that I have. So yes I do, the covariance matrix is then given by $R_{s} + \sigma_{v}^{2} I$, correct? So given that, how can I relate that to the $\hat{a}_{p}$ -- just compute each one?